# powershell set category for multiple files and subdirectories

Tags: powershell, categories

I've been putting "tags" into the names of files, but that's a terrible way of organizing a large number of files.

ex: "ABC - file name.docx"

So, I want to set the category attribute to "ABC" instead of having it in the name using PowerShell. The script would have to find all of the files with "ABC" in its name in the subdirectories of a certain folder and set the category attribute to "ABC".

So I have the first part where I am finding the files but I don't know where to go from here.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "ABC*" -Recurse
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I know I can get all the files with "ABC" in its name by using `Get-ChildItem -Filter "ABC*" -Recurse` but I don't know how to set the category for all of these files.

Comment: I'm confused by the words you are using to describe your problem. Files do not have an "category attribute". File attributes are just on/off flags. What exactly are you trying to change? The part of the name before the dash?

Comment: @Matt I mean the category tag under properties > details for a document. I could do it manually, but I don't want to for so many files.

Comment: Ah ok.... text files dont normally have these. Are you trying to add them to text files or are these all word documents?

Comment: @Matt They're all word documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this borrow heavily from the [Scripting Guys](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/04/06/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-add-custom-properties-to-a-microsoft-word-document.aspx). What we need to do is for every file we find use the a Word COM object to access those special properties of the file. Using the current file name we extract the "category" by splitting on the first hyphen and saving both parts. First becomes the category and second is the new name we give the file assuming the category update was successful.

There is still margin for error with this but this

```psh
$path = "C:\temp"

# Create the Word com object and hide it sight
$wordApplication = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$wordApplication.Visible = $false

# Typing options for located Word Documents. Mainly to prevent changes to timestamps
$binding = "System.Reflection.BindingFlags" -as [type]

# Locate Documents.
$docs = Get-childitem -path $Path -Recurse -Filter "*-*.docx"
$docs | ForEach-Object{
    $currentDocumentPath = $_.fullname
    $document = $wordApplication.documents.open($currentDocumentPath)
    $BuiltinProperties = $document.BuiltInDocumentProperties
    $builtinPropertiesType = $builtinProperties.GetType()
    $categoryUpdated = $false  # Assume false as a reset of the state.

    # Get the category from the file name for this particular file.
    $filenamesplit =  $_.Name.split("-",2)
    $category = $filenamesplit[0].Trim()

    # Attempt to change the property.
    Try{ 
        $BuiltInProperty = $builtinPropertiesType.invokemember("item",$binding::GetProperty,$null,$BuiltinProperties,"Category")  
        $BuiltInPropertyType = $BuiltInProperty.GetType()
        $BuiltInPropertyType.invokemember("value",$binding::SetProperty,$null,$BuiltInProperty,[array]$category)
        $categoryUpdated = $true
    }Catch [system.exception]{
        # Error getting property so most likely is not populated. 
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Unable to set the 'Category' for '$currentDocumentPath'" 
    }

    # Close the document. It should save by default. 
    $document.close()

    # Release COM objects to ensure process is terminated and document closed. 
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($BuiltinProperties) | Out-Null
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($document) | Out-Null
    Remove-Variable -Name document, BuiltinProperties

    # Assuming the category was successfully changed lets remove the information from the current filename as it is redundant.
    If($categoryUpdated){Rename-Item $currentDocumentPath -NewName $filenamesplit[1].Trim()}
}

$wordApplication.quit()
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wordApplication) | Out-Null
Remove-Variable -Name wordApplication
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

You should see some explanation in comments that I tried to add for clarification. Also read the link above to get more of an explanation as to what is happening with the COM object.